# Why VB Shell function does not stop Python code execution window?

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell

The python code execution using the excel VB Shell function does not stop at python instructions. It quickly opens and closes but does not show Python instructions. The following excel macro runs the python code:

```
Sub run_python()
    
    python_exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"
    python_script = "C:/Users/Goerge/OneDrive - MS Corporation/Documents/Development/python-excel/excel_python.py"
    
    If Dir(python_exe) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Python executable does not exists")
    End If
    
    If Dir(python_script) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Python script does not exists")
    End If
    
    python_code = python_exe & " " & " -k " & python_script
    
    RetVal = Shell(python_code)
    
End Sub
```

The example python code :

```py
import os
    
print("This is first python function called in excel")
for x in range(0,9999999999999999999):
    print("Counting : ", x)
    #input('Press ENTER to exit')
os.system("pause")
```

I added few steps here (for loop and "pause") to hold the code execution but it does not respond when executed through macro. However, this code works as expected when directly run in VS code.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using Excel 365 and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to spaces in the path. Spaces in the python path are fine but Python script path should not have any spaces. When there are spaces, it is broken into separated variables and never sees the script as a file. So the fix is to have double quotations to the path with spaces.

VB script should be as follows :

```
Sub run_python()

python_exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"
python_script = "C:/Users/Goerge/OneDrive - MS Corporation/Documents/Development/python-excel/excel_python.py"

If Dir(python_exe) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Python executabl does not exists")
End If

If Dir(python_script) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Python script does not exists")
End If

python_code = python_exe & " " & """" & python_script & """"
MsgBox python_code
RetVal = Shell(python_code)

'Shell "pskill " & " " & RetVal

End Sub
```